# C program compiles but doesn't run

Tags: c, makefile, dev-c++

I have written a program for an assignment and it complies but it does not execute. I have tried creating new files to for the code but this has not helped. In the past when it has worked half of the project will work but the file access part of it hasn't worked.

This is the error that shows up when i execute the program:

Failed to execute "D:\Compter programming\Project\cass.exe": 
Error 193: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

This is the code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

const int SIZE = 18;                                                                /* This is seting up the size of the array called SIZE, the code will use this rather than using a number */ 

void calc_freq (int[]);                                                             /* These are the function prototypes*/          
void ind(double, int[], double[]);
void cap(double, int[], double[]);
void att(double, double, int[], double[]);
void attdb(double, double, int[], double[], double[]);
void screenprint (int[], double[], double[], double[], double[]);
void fileprint (int[], double[], double[], double[], double[]);


int main (void) {
    int frequencies[SIZE], n;

    double ind_react[SIZE], cap_react[SIZE], attenuation[SIZE], attenuationdb[SIZE] ;
    double L, C;


    printf("Enter inductance in milli Henrys\n");
    scanf("%lf",&L);
    L = L / 1000;                                                                   /* Convert from milli Henies to Henries */

    printf("Enter capacitance in Farads\n");
    scanf("%lf",&C);
    C = C / 1000000;                                                                /* Converts from miro Farads to Farads */


    calc_freq (frequencies);                                                        /* function prototypes*/
    ind(L, frequencies, ind_react);
    cap(C, frequencies, cap_react);
    att(L, C, frequencies, attenuation);
    attdb(L, C, frequencies, attenuation, attenuationdb);
    screenprint (frequencies, ind_react, cap_react, attenuation, attenuationdb);
    fileprint (frequencies, ind_react, cap_react, attenuation, attenuationdb);


    return 0;

}

void calc_freq (int numbers[SIZE])                      
{
    int n;

    for (n=0; n<9; n++)
    {
        numbers[n] = 100*(n+1);                                                     /* This equation helps frequncy go up in 100s */                    

    }

    for (n=9; n<18; n++)
    {
        numbers[n] = 1000*(n-8);                                                    /* This equations helps frequency go up in 1000s */

    }
}


void ind(double L, int frequencies[], double ind_react[])
{

    int i;
    for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
    {
        ind_react[i] = 2*M_PI*frequencies[i]*L;                                     /* in the math library PI is M_PI */
    }
}

void cap(double C, int frequencies[], double cap_react[])
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
    {
        cap_react[i] = 1/(2*M_PI*frequencies[i]*C);
    }

}

void att(double L, double C, int frequencies[], double attenuation[])
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
    {
        attenuation[i] = 1/((1)-(2*M_PI*frequencies[i]*2*M_PI*frequencies[i])*L*C);             
        if (attenuation[i] <0)  
        {
        attenuation[i] = attenuation[i] * (-1);
        }
    }   

}

void attdb(double L, double C, int frequencies[], double attenuation[], double attenuationdb[])
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
    {
        attenuation[i] = 1/((1)-(2*M_PI*frequencies[i]*2*M_PI*frequencies[i])*L*C);
        if (attenuation[i] <0)  
        {
        attenuation[i] = attenuation[i] * (-1);                                     /* the (-1) gets rid of the negative attenuation anwers which can't be used in the log expression */
        }

        attenuationdb[i] = 20*log10 (attenuation[i]);

    }   

} 

void screenprint (int frequencies[SIZE], double ind_react[SIZE], double cap_react[SIZE], double attenuation[SIZE], double attenuationdb[SIZE])
{
    printf("\nFREQUENCIES\tINDUCTIVE REACTANCE\tCAPACITIVE REAVTANCE\tATTENUATION\tATTENUATION (dB)\n");                /* this will put the calculated answers in a table form */
    printf("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n"); 

    int n; 
    for (n=0; n<18; n++)
    {
    printf ("%4i\t %18.3lf\t %18.3lf\t %14.3lf\t %14.3lf\n",frequencies[n], ind_react[n], cap_react[n], attenuation[n], attenuationdb[n]);  
    }   
    /* puting a number after '%' will change the indent between each column of the table    and adding a decimal to tht number controls the number of decimal places of the values */
}

void fileprint (int frequencies[SIZE], double ind_react[SIZE], double cap_react[SIZE], double attenuation[SIZE], double attenuationdb[SIZE])
{

char filename[200];


FILE *f_ptr;                                                                        /* *f_ptr creates a file pointer */

printf("Enter the full name of the output file: ");

scanf("%s", filename);                                                              /* This line scans the file name and puts it into the filename */

/*Open the file for writing */

f_ptr = fopen(filename, "w");                                                       /* "w" for write mode */
int n; 
    for (n=0; n<18; n++)
{
fprintf (f_ptr,"%4i\t %18.3lf\t %18.3lf\t %14.3lf\t %14.3lf\n",frequencies[n], ind_react[n], cap_react[n], attenuation[n], attenuationdb[n]);
}

fclose(f_ptr);                                                                      /* Close the file */


}
```

Comment: your program runs well (under Linux), your problem is not the program/code itself, how you compiled it ? It seems it was for instance compiled for a 64b Windows version

Comment: How do you build your program?

Comment: Also please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [**Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I compiled on a 64gb windows computer using Dev C++,  but that is one of the requirements for the assignment i also have a mac which i have tried to run the code on.

Comment: @Ije so I was right, you cannot execute a 64b program on your 32b WIndows (error says _Win32_)

Comment: When you say "64gb Windows" do you mean 64 *bit* Windows? What compiler is Dev-C++ using? GCC I assume, but what *version* of it? What flags are given to the compiler when you build? Can you get a verbose build log output that shows all the files being compiled and linked, and what flags and options were passed to the compiler and linker?

Comment: @bruno "WIN32" doesn't necessarily mean 32-bit Windows. Like "the WIN32 API" is still used for the Windows system API, independently of the target platform hardware word-size.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude really ? this is a weird message in that case  ^^

Comment: @bruno Though after a quick Googling, I might be wrong...

Comment: @Ije if you go into the directory ""D:\Compter programming\Project" then execute "cass.exe" do you have the same error ? If not the problem is just your way to start it, and the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/55879486/2458991 is the right one

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude sorry to say but I hope your was wrong, not against you but for Windows ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this windows File path D:\Compter programming\Project\cass.exe", there seems to be a **space**.

Because of this, it may not detect the application type.

The link have the explanation for this.
https://support.symantec.com/en_US/article.TECH11171.html